# My program sometimes works and sometimes it doesn't

Tags: java

I made a WordCount program that counts the amount of words in a file and it seems to work at first but if you keep running it just breaks? If I remove a blank line it also breaks the programs. I feel like it has something to do with my locks? How would you guys fix this?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;

public class WordCount implements Runnable {

    public static Lock CountLock;
    public static Lock CombinedWordCountLock;
    public static int CombinedWordCount = 0;
    private String file;

    public WordCount(String file) {

        this.file = file; 

    }

    public void run() {
        WordCount.CountLock = new ReentrantLock();
        CountLock.lock(); 

        int count = 0;

        try {

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
            while(scan.hasNext()) { 
                scan.next(); 
                count++; 
            }

        } catch(IOException exception) {
            System.out.println("\n" + file + " not found"); 
            CountLock.unlock();
        }


        System.out.println(file + ": " + count); 
        WordCount.CombinedWordCountLock = new ReentrantLock();
        CombinedWordCountLock.lock(); 
        CombinedWordCount += count;
        CountLock.lock();
            System.out.println("combined count: " +  CombinedWordCount); 
            CountLock.unlock();
            CombinedWordCountLock.unlock();
        }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        if(args.length < 1) {
                System.out.println("\n" + "Error, please put txt files after Java WordCount");
                return;
            }   

        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) { 
            WordCount wc = new WordCount(args[i]);
            Thread t = new Thread(wc); 
            t.start(); 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take care of Java naming conventions. Variable names should start with lowercase character. Do not make properties `public`

Comment: Every `run()` creates new locks. If you actually want to lock anything, you'll have to make the thraeds use the *same* locks. Though I fail to see the point of in-process locking when you're accessing files. Shouldn't you lock the file then, to prevent access from _other_ processes while you're counting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you start a new thread, you recreate the locks `WordCount.CountLock` and `WordCount.CombinedWordCountLock`.

You should only create your locks *once* (e.g. in the `main` function) and have all the threads share that single instance of them.